# Reverse geocode can't find address using coordinates returned by geocode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, capybara, semaphore, rails-geocoder

We're using the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/) gem in our app. In a test, we're using the following address:

> 4 Cork Oak Rd, Welgevonden, Stellenbosch

Geocoding it returns the following coordinates:

```
[39] pry(main)> coord = Geocoder.search("4 Cork Oak Rd, Welgevonden, Stellenbosch")[0].geometry["location"]
=> {"lat"=>-33.9023262, "lng"=>18.851008}
```

But when I reverse geocode those exact coordinates, I get nothing:

```
[46] pry(main)> Geocoder.search("#{coord['lat']}, #{coord['lng']}")
=> []
```

What gives?!

As far as I can tell/remember, this issue is only happening as of today. It breaks every single time on my machine, and yet it hasn't failed once on Semaphore. No configuration changes have happened since Friday.

If I round the coordinates to 6 decimal places, I do get the desired result:

```
[55] pry(main)> Geocoder.search("#{coord['lat'].round(6)}, #{coord['lng'].round(6)}")
=> [#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x0000011738bdd8
  @cache_hit=true,
  @data=
   {"address_components"=>
     [{"long_name"=>"Cork Oak Road"...
```

I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require altering precision where it never caused a problem before.

Comment: Goeie middag Henre. If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Accuracy, you'll see that 6 decimal points has a precision of within 43mm, which is perfectly adequate for most applications. Something to take into account if you struggle with a solution

Comment: Jis Marco :) Yes, I did look at that article. It's not a bad solution, I guess, but I feel like reducing the float precision doesn't really address the root problem of Geocoder/Google returning non-reversible coordinates. But then I don't have access to their codebases, do I? :D

Comment: Yes. It's open source: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just watched the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) code, and i found the `Geocoder.address()` function, i tried with your coordinates, and `Geocoder.address('-33.9023262, 18.851008')` returns me `Cork Oak Road, Stellenbosch`. I also tried with a 13 decimal latitude, it works too

- If you want to get **coordinates from address**, use `Geocoder.search()`.
- If you want to get **address from coordinates**, use `Geocoder.address()`

According to the [code available on GitHub](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/examples/reverse_geocode_job.rb#L28).

If you want complete informations about the place you can use `Geocoder.search(Geocoder.address('-33.9023262, 18.851008'))`, but it is two HTTP requests sent to Google servers.

In my opinion, **best solution is** to round to 6 decimals and send only one request, you only lose *43.496 mm* of precision.

You have to chose between an absolute precision or send two HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the `address` method. I need the true results object, though! (This code is being used in a callback whose purpose is to extract properties like the city and country.) What baffles me is that `Geocoder.search` *does* work, it just doesn't work if the decimal precision is too high. :/

Comment: `Geocoder.search(Geocoder.address('-33.9023262, 18.851008'))` is actually working as wanted returning a `Geocoder::Result::Google` object, but it is two HTTP requests. You got a choice, round to 6 decimals, or send two requests to Google servers. I'll edit my response.

Comment: Meh. Wish there were a better solution! But I'm accepting yours for now. Thanks mate.