# Why does Google's Reverse Geocoding API not return the same places as the Autocomplete Api?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm working on a tool that will extract a location from JPEG exif lat/lng values, but also let the user set a location manually if not present in exif data.

I'm experiencing some weirdness with Google's reverse geocoding API where it seems unable to find major tourist attractions when I have accurately provided a lat/lng right at the location, even when the same location is findable with Google's places autocomplete API. For example:

If I search for "Tian Tan Buddha" in the autocomplete API, one of the results I get is this place ID: `ChIJMU72avZYATQRcPDlSybkD00` (https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:ChIJMU72avZYATQRcPDlSybkD00). the `latlng` value from the autocomplete API result is `22.2539847,113.904984`, so I take that and try to reverse geocode the *exact same coordinates*:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.2539847,113.904984&key=[my_key]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.2539847,113.904984&key=%5Bmy_key%5D)

This yields eight results, all broadly in the right place, none of which is is place ID `ChIJMU72avZYATQRcPDlSybkD00` and none of which has "Tian Tan Buddha" in any field within the result set.

I'm seeing this same effect all on photos from all over the world - at Buckingham Palace, in large sports arenas etc.

Can anyone shine any light on why the reverse geocoding API would be incapable of returning results that are absolutely positively right at the provided lat/lng coordinates and known to Google?

Comment: Try rounding to 6 decimal digits. This has [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321735/geocode-api-coordinates-not-recognized-by-the-reverse-geocode-api-zero-results) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114579/reverse-geocode-cant-find-address-using-coordinates-returned-by-geocode). Right now your latitude has 7. Also remember that the reverse geocoding API primarily returns addresses. It can also return POIs but that's not its main purpose.

Comment: The reverse geocoder returns mainly postal addresses and some places of interest.  The autocomplete uses Google's Places database, which will return additional "places" (if it is configured to)

Comment: Use the places service and do a nearby search with a location and radius. With a 50m radius, the first result I get is `ChIJMU72avZYATQRcPDlSybkD00`.

Comment: Thanks very much all - that's really helpful :) The 6 decimal thing didn't help unfortunately, but using the places "nearby" API does something much closer to what I want. I'll need to use the two APIs in combination I think since not every photo will be near to a "place" but I can try one followed by the other. @MrUpsidown, happy to accept that as the answer if you want to add it :)